# Choosing a convergence test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Consider $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{10 n}.$$

I have been working on this problem but I am stuck on which convergence test to use. The series does not diverge by the Divergence Test.
The given solution by the textbook says the series converges to $\frac{-\ln2}{10}$, but I do not understand how they reached that solution.

Comment: Do you know how to deal  with the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}?$$  If so, note that your series is that series, modulo a factor of 10.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe we covered alternating harmonic series in class. However, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges by the Leibniz criterion. Furthermore,

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{10n} = \frac{1}{10} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = \frac{1}{10} \cdot (-\ln(2)),$$

where we have used the well-known formula for the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: "Well known"...

Answer (score 2):

Your series is $-\frac1{10}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n$ converge by the Leibniz test. And, by Abel's theorem\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}n\\&=\lim_{x\to1^-}\log(x+1)\\&=\log 2.\end{align}